# How to properly delete nodes in a bst? in c

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, free

```
struct treeNode {
    char word[10];
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
    struct treeNode *father;

};
struct treeNode* getMin(struct treeNode *node)
{
    while (node->left != NULL) {
        node = node->left;
    }
    return node;
}
void deleteNode(struct treeNode *node) {

char tempForDelete[10];
    struct treeNode *parent = node->father;

    if (node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
    {

        if (node != root)
        {
            if (parent->left == node) {
                parent->left = NULL;
            }
            else {
                parent->right = NULL;
            }
        }
        else {
            root = NULL;
        }
        free(node);

    }

    else if (node->left != NULL && node->right !=NULL)
    {
        struct treeNode* successor = getMin(node->right);

        strcpy(tempForDelete, successor->word);


        deleteNode(successor);

        strcpy(node->word,tempForDelete);
    }

    else {
        struct treeNode* child;

        if (node->left != NULL)
            child = node->left;
        else
            child = node->right;

        if (node != root)
        {
            if (node == parent->left) {
                parent->left = child;
            }
            else {
                parent->right = child;
            }
        }
        else {
            root = child;
        }
        free(node);
    }

}
void filterDictionary(struct treeNode *root)
{
   if (root == NULL) {
        return;
    }


    filterDictionary(root->left);
    filterDictionary(root->right);
    if (checkNode(root) == 1)
        deleteNode(root);
}
```

checkNode just check if the node has to be deleted, i keep getting the same errors from valgrind: Invalid write of size
Address 0x4a4e4c8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd
(A lot of these :,)  )
If needed i can also provide the code for deletNode but i'm pretty sure that the function works correctly.
(I also tried the iterative way but it was the same thing).
Has anyone any ideas what i'm doing wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for days and i can't find a way :((
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "but i'm pretty sure that the function works correctly" famous last words.  It cannot possibly work correctly, the signature is wrong. And `filterDictionary` signature is also wrong, for the same reason.

Comment: How does your code unlink the to-be-deleted node from the parent node that pointed to it? Does each treeNode have a back-pointer? You should include the definition of treeNode and your deleteNode code.

Comment: I have a crystal ball. It's long overdue to be serviced but somehow I manage to get useful predictions out of it sometimes. It says that you expect `deleteNode(root)` to make `root` a null pointer. Is it right?

Comment: I've added the deleteNode function and the definition of treeNode; but why you say the signature is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem in deleteNode from a cursory review. How confident are you about the code that built the BST and inserted new nodes? Also, presumably you have verified that there's no chance of a `word` actually being more than 9 chars in length.

Comment: I didn't take into account that you used a global variable. Normally global variables are frowned upon.

Comment: Yes, the code works fine(or at least i think so...i've tested it many times before triyng to delete nodes and it worked perfectly), and the words are all 5 chars long.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes i have used tons of global variables.

Comment: I actually cannot find any obvious failure in posted code (except that there are global variables; don't use them). Perhaps post a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help guys, i'll see if i can create a minimal reproduble example, even though it's gonna be tough since the program it's 800 lines long :,)